# Numpy array - pixel coordinates

Tags: numpy, mask

I am trying to convert a black and white picture, represented as a numpy array with the shape `(640,480,1)` - where `640 is the x` value, - `480 the y` value, and the last one either a `0 or a 1` representing the mask.
Now I am trying to covert this array in a `(640*480,2)` array, where the `rows represent 0 or 1`, and the `columns` represent the `x and y` value.
I have absolutely no clue on how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're one-hot encoding (I think) and the easiest way to do that with `numpy` is by indexing `np.eye(number_of_categories)`

```
img = np.random.randint(2, (640,480,1))
out = np.eye(2)[img.ravel()]

out.shape
Out[]: (307200, 2)
```

Not sure why you'd want to one-hot encode a binary value though.